# Converting HTML Files into a PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I have a website that displays product information that the client wishes to offer as pdf format. I need a way to dynamically convert a particular HTML page into a PDF, does anybody know of a way to do this? I need to convert an html page into a PDF document and serve it to the end user on the fly (there are WAY too many products to do this manually and these products receive updates regularly so a manual approach is out of the question)

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I need this to use either vb.net or c#.net

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Comment: oops I forgot, I'm working with c#.net or vb.net (either of the 2 is fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried iTextSharp?